# ruby - redirect_to(url, :myparam => 'abc')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, param, redirecttoaction

I can't work this out.

```
url = "www.mysite.com/?param1=abc"

redirect_to(url, :param2 => 'xyz')

### Should this go to - www.mysite.com/?param1=abc&param2=xyz
```

Or am I missing something? It doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to):

> **redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})**
>
> Redirects the browser to the target specified in options. This
>   parameter can take one of three forms:
>
> Hash - The URL will be generated by calling url_for with the options.
>
> Record - The URL will be generated by calling url_for with the
>   options, which will reference a named URL for that record.
>
> String starting with protocol:// (like http://) or a protocol relative
>   reference (like //) - Is passed straight through as the target for
>   redirection.

You're passing a String as the first argument, so it's using the 3rd option. Your second parameter is interpreted as the value for the `response_status` parameter.

So, if your redirect is an internal one (to the same app), you don't need to specify the scheme and hostname. Just use

```
redirect_to root_url(param1 => 'abc', param2 => 'xyz')
```

If it's an external URL, build the *complete* URL before redirecting:

```
url = "www.mysite.com/?param1=abc&params2=xyz"
redirect_to url
```

Answer (score 4):

`redirect_to` is not a Ruby function but is commonly used in Ruby on Rails. You can find its documentation with a lot of working examples [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to).

If you want to open a website within plain Ruby, use the 'open-uri' class. You can find its documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html).

I hope this helps understanding why `redirect_to` doesn't work in plain Ruby and might help using it with and without Rails.

Answer (score 2):

it won't know about the old params unless you merge them in and send them on.

```
url = "www.mysite.com/?param1=abc"
p = params.merge({:param2 => 'xyz'})
redirect_to(url, p)
```